# How to initialize a 2d array and how to access it from a main method in java?

Tags: java, class, constructor

The 2d array created overwrites the previously created 2d array each time the loop continues, how can I create a seperate 2d array and access/change it in the way listed below.

I'm currently a highschool student taking an online computer sciences course and would like to improve my efficiency with coding and get some tips on bad habbits I have. Here is my program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FundRaising 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Would you like to input donation information regarding the selected schools?\n0 - Yes\n1 - No"); //runs the program or ends the program
        Integer loop = scanner.nextInt();

        while (loop == 0) //while the user would like to run the program, the code will look
            {
            if (loop == 0) //continues if the user would like to continue
                {
                System.out.println("Which school is fundraising?\n0 - Central\n1 - Holy Cross\n2 - John Paul II\n3 - Teresa\n4 - Regina\n5 - Joeseph\n6 - Mary\n7 - Thomas Aquinas");
                Integer school = scanner.nextInt(); //asks which school information will be input for

                System.out.println("Amount donated?\n0 - 25 cents\n1 - 50 cents\n2 - 1 dollar\n3 - 2 dollars");
                Integer donation = scanner.nextInt(); //asks the amount donated

                System.out.println("School population?");
                Integer population = scanner.nextInt(); //asks the population of the school





                if (donation == 0) //if the first donation amount is selected then this selection will be used
                    {
                    double schoolTotal = 0.25*population; //the donation amount times the population gives the total for the school selected
                    System.out.println("  Cen Cross Paul Trsa Rgna Joes Mary Tom  Amnt Total"); //prints out headers for the 2d array



                    int rows = 4; //set the initial size of the 2d array according to schools and donations
                    int columns = 10;
                    double totals [][] = new double [rows][columns]; //initialize the 2d array
                    totals[0][8] = 0.25;
                    totals[1][8] = 0.5; //set various positions on the 2d array to equal the donation amounts
                    totals[2][8] = 1.00;
                    totals[3][8] = 2.00;
                    totals[donation][school] = schoolTotal; //set the positions corredsponding to the input school and donation in order to create a "total" column on the 2d array
                    totals[donation][9] = totals[0][0]+totals[0][1]+totals[0][2]+totals[0][3]+totals[0][4]+totals[0][5]+totals[0][6]+totals[0][7]; //the sums of everything in the row is used to find a value for the total column


                    double finalDonations = totals[0][9]+totals[1][9]+totals[2][9]+totals[3][9]; //adds the total for each school in the total column to create a final total for donations


                    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(totals).replace("], ", "]\n ")); //prints out the 2d array with slight modifications for easier viewing
                    System.out.println("\nTotals donations:" + finalDonations +""); //prints the total amount of donations to the user




                    }





                if (donation == 1) //each subsequence if statement is used if the donation amount differs (4 different donations amounts, 25 cents, 50 cents, 1 dollar and 2 dollars
                    { //remainder of code is drycut paste with small modifications to adjust for differing donation amount
                    double schoolTotal = 0.50*population;
                    System.out.println("  Cen Cross Paul Trsa Rgna Joes Mary Tom  Amnt Total");



                    int rows = 4;
                    int columns = 10;
                    double totals [][] = new double [rows][columns];
                    totals[0][8] = 0.25;
                    totals[1][8] = 0.5;
                    totals[2][8] = 1.00;
                    totals[3][8] = 2.00;
                    totals[donation][school] = schoolTotal;
                    totals[donation][9] = totals[1][0]+totals[1][1]+totals[1][2]+totals[1][3]+totals[1][4]+totals[1][5]+totals[1][6]+totals[1][7];


                    double finalDonations = totals[0][9]+totals[1][9]+totals[2][9]+totals[3][9];


                    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(totals).replace("], ", "]\n "));
                    System.out.println("\nTotals donations:" + finalDonations +"");


                    }


                if (donation == 2)
                    {
                    double schoolTotal = 1.00*population;
                    System.out.println("  Cen Cross Paul Trsa Rgna Joes Mary Tom  Amnt Total");



                    int rows = 4;
                    int columns = 10;
                    double totals [][] = new double [rows][columns];
                    totals[0][8] = 0.25;
                    totals[1][8] = 0.5;
                    totals[2][8] = 1.00;
                    totals[3][8] = 2.00;
                    totals[donation][school] = schoolTotal;
                    totals[donation][9] = totals[2][0]+totals[2][1]+totals[2][2]+totals[2][3]+totals[2][4]+totals[2][5]+totals[2][6]+totals[2][7];


                    double finalDonations = totals[0][9]+totals[1][9]+totals[2][9]+totals[3][9];


                    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(totals).replace("], ", "]\n "));
                    System.out.println("\nTotals donations:" + finalDonations +"");


                    }


                if (donation == 3)
                    {
                    double schoolTotal = 2.00*population;
                    System.out.println("  Cen Cross Paul Trsa Rgna Joes Mary Tom  Amnt Total");



                    int rows = 4;
                    int columns = 10;
                    double totals [][] = new double [rows][columns];
                    totals[0][8] = 0.25;
                    totals[1][8] = 0.5;
                    totals[2][8] = 1.00;
                    totals[3][8] = 2.00;
                    totals[donation][school] = schoolTotal;
                    totals[donation][9] = totals[3][0]+totals[3][1]+totals[3][2]+totals[3][3]+totals[3][4]+totals[3][5]+totals[3][6]+totals[3][7];


                    double finalDonations = totals[0][9]+totals[1][9]+totals[2][9]+totals[3][9];


                    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(totals).replace("], ", "]\n "));
                    System.out.println("\nTotals donations:" + finalDonations +"");


                    }

                }




            else //if the user did not chose to run the program this message is displayed
                {
                        System.out.println("You did not not choose to input information");
                }

            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask including: "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence". Please post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually create new array each loop iteration.

Just move this part

```
int rows = 4; //set the initial size of the 2d array according to schools and donations
int columns = 10;
double totals [][] = new double [rows][columns]; //initialize the 2d array
```

to the main method, just after the `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` , and erase it from inside the loop, so the donation values for previous schools don't get overwritten the next time.

Then, if you want the sum of the donation increase you should change the

`totals[donation][school] = schoolTotal;` to

```
totals[donation][school] = totals[donation][school] + schoolTotal;
```

or else leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your question is, but i recommend you to start using for loops instead of code repetition.

lines like this:

`totals[donation][9] = totals[0][0]+totals[0][1]+totals[0][2]+totals[0][3]+totals[0][4]+totals[0][5]+totals[0][6]+totals[0][7];`

should be replaced by:

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) (or i<totals[0].length if you want to run on all the cells)
    totals[donation][9]+=totals[0][i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Collections` instead of arrays for manipulating data like this. E.g. a `Map<String, Integer>` for working with different donation sources and values